# Bitwise XOR operator c# and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

There is code on javascript

```
const a = 2654435769;        
const b = 7562089;        
console.log(a ^ b); // answer -1639703856
```

When you try to rewrite this code on C #, I ran into a problem.

```
long a = 2654435769;
long b = 7562089;
var result = a ^ b; // result = 2655263440;
```

Why do you get answers in different languages? And how to get the same answer on C # on JavaScript

Comment: Probably by using an `int` instead of a `long` (don't know C#). JS uses 32bit signed integer bitwise operations.

Comment: It's a bitwise XOR operator, not a logical XOR operator. Javascript converts numbers into **signed** 32-bit integers to perform bitwise operators.

Answer (score 3):

The [ECMAScript Specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-numberbitwiseop) describes that for all bitwise operations on numbers, they will be converted to 32 bit integers before applying the operator. To obtain the same result in C# you can cast your operands to `int`:

```
long a = 2654435769;
long b = 7562089;
var result = (int)a ^ (int)b; // result = -1639703856;
```

Relevant bits from the spec in case the link goes stale in the future:

[image: Number::bitwiseXOR]

[image: NumberBitwiseOp]